# Surface mounting a metal weatherproof junction box on a concrete slab

Tags: electrical

US, Southern CA, NEC 2017

**Background**

I'm currently in the planning stages for a project that will include running a circuit in some buried conduit (likely RMC) to a concrete slab. At the slab I'd like to add a junction box to split the circuit off in two different directions. The concrete slab is already poured, so encasing any conduit or boxes isn't an option.

I was thinking of surface mounting a junction box on the concrete slab, something like McMaster part #7219K71:

[image: round metal weatherproof junction box]

Proposed:

1. RMC conduit to the slab
2. 90 deg sweep to top edge of slab
3. LB conduit body at edge of slab
4. conduit nipple
5. round metal weatherproof junction box

In this location, the junction box, conduit body, and conduit would be exposed to the elements and could be stepped on, but it's not expected to be a high-traffic area.

### Questions

1. Is "surface mounted to a concrete slab" a valid location to install a junction box?
2. Is this type of metal weatherproof junction box suitable to install in this location?
3. Are there cases where conduit is allowed to be secured to the floor for short distances, or must it always be secured to a vertical surface?

Comment: Vertical or horizontal each conduit will require an anchor. Why not use a standard bell box? They make heavier covers for them.  Surface mounted on the slab is legal bending the “kick” in rigid can be a challenge for diy but can be done with a hand bender.

Comment: @EdBeal I went with a round box for the four orthogonal hub exits, which I thought would work better for my specific use case, but I'm not opposed to a rectangular box. Aside from the additional cu. in. for splices or availability of heavier covers, are there code reasons to go with a rectangular metal weatherproof box?